# MongoDB Batch read implementation issue with change stream replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set, changestream, mongodb-replica

**Issue:**
A inference generating process is writing around 300 inference data's to a MongoDB collection per second. Change stream feature of MongoDB is utilized by another process to read back back these inferences and do the post-processing. Currently, **only a single inference data is returned** when the change stream function API (mongoc_change_stream_next())is called. So, a total of 300 such calls is required to get all inference data stored within 1 second. However, after each read, **around 50ms of time is required to perform the post-processing** for single/multiple inference data. Because of the single data return model, **an effective latency of 15x is introduced**. To tackle this issue, we are trying to implement a **batch read mechanism in-line with change stream feature of MongoDB**. We tried various options to implement the same, but still getting only one data after each change stream API call. Is there any way to sort out this issue?

**Platform:**
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Mongo-c-driver: 1.15.1
Mongo server : 4.0.12

**Options tried out:**
Setting the batch size of the cursor to more than 1.

```
int main(void) {
    const char *uri_string = "mongodb://localhost:27017/replicaSet=set0";
    mongoc_change_stream_t *stream;
    mongoc_collection_t *coll;
    bson_error_t error;
        mongoc_uri_t *uri;
    mongoc_client_t *client;

    /*
    * Add the Mongo DB blocking read and scall the inference parse function with the Json
                 * */
    uri = mongoc_uri_new_with_error (uri_string, &error);
    if (!uri) {
        fprintf (stderr,
        "failed to parse URI: %s\n"
        "error message:       %s\n",
        uri_string,
        error.message);
        return -1;
    }

    client = mongoc_client_new_from_uri (uri);
    if (!client) {
        return -1;
    }

    coll = mongoc_client_get_collection (client,  <DB-NAME>, <collection-name>);
    stream = mongoc_collection_watch (coll, &empty, NULL);
    mongoc_cursor_set_batch_size(stream->cursor, 20);
    while (1){
        while (mongoc_change_stream_next (stream, &doc)) {
            char *as_json = bson_as_relaxed_extended_json (doc, NULL); 
            ............
            ............
            //post processing consuming 50 ms of time
            ............
            ............
        }
        if (mongoc_change_stream_error_document (stream, &error, &err_doc)) {
            if (!bson_empty (err_doc)) {
                fprintf (stderr,
                "Server Error: %s\n",
                bson_as_relaxed_extended_json (err_doc, NULL));
            } else {
                fprintf (stderr, "Client Error: %s\n", error.message);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, only a single inference data is returned when the change
>   stream function API (mongoc_change_stream_next())is called

Technically it's not that a single document is returned. This is because [mongoc_change_stream_next()](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/1.15.3/src/libmongoc/doc/mongoc_change_stream_next.rst) iterates the underlying cursor, setting each `bson` to the next document. So, even the batch size returned is more than one, it still has to iterate per document.

You could try:

- Create separate threads to process the documents in parallel, so you don't have to wait 50ms per document or 15 seconds accumulatively.
- Loop through a batch of documents, i.e. 50 cache them then perform a batch processing
- Batch process them on separate threads (combination of the two above)